# stl algorithms, constexpr, C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, constexpr

I think everybody knows that starting from `C++20` there comes a huge improvement to the language. From other significant improvements I wanted to mention these. So `std::copy` `std::move` and `std::transform` are becoming `constexpr`. The strange thing was that all `iterator` accessors are already `constexpr` but these functions not. And if you think about their implementation, I think just adding `constexpr` in front of them will do the job.

So I have a question.

*Is it ok to write my own implementation of these functions with `constexpr` added?* *Will I gain more performance?*

Comment: `constexpr` != "effortless performance gain". There are many posts on SO itself where people are bewildered when this expectation isn't met.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you writing a library that looks like the C++ standard library (STL is no longer a correct terminology).  Just don't place your library in `std` unless you want undefined behaviour.   You will also need to take care to ensure functions/types/etc in your library don't unintentionally interact in strange ways with the standard library.   I wouldn't lay bets that you would achieve more performance though - it takes more than sprinkling keywords like `constexpr` around to reliably improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to write my own implementation of these functions with `constexpr` added?

If it is well-defined, then it is okay. Your implementations must have different names or be in a different namespace because you mustn't replace `std::` versions.

> Will I gain more performance?

Use a profiler or write a benchmark to answer this question.

Comment: In fact I think with optimization level -O3 it becomes the same assembly :)

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan That's not unheard of.